# VBA: Access element inside a div loaded with angularjs, when ID and Classname changes randomly

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am a beginner in VBA and I make an application that fills the data coming from a xls page to a website that uses angularjs.
the website contains a table to fill out, so its ID and classname changes the four latest number randomly with each refresh. (for exemple: the code source below: 02XC of ID will be change to something different, but the prefix will remain the same).   how can i manipulate this table?

**Code source web site**

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-02XC cell editable" id="1554799061475-1-uiGrid-02XC-cell" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-cell="" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'">[Here is the web table that i want to upload values][1]</div>
```

**my code**

```vb
Set objHtml = New HTMLDocument
Set objHtml = internetExplorer.document

Set modric = objHtml.getElementsByClassName("ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-02XC cell editable")
If modric.Length <> 0 Then
 For q = 0 To modric.Length - 1
      modric(q).Click
      modric(q).innerText = Workbooks("remplir").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F1").Offset(n + 1, 0).Value
Next q
End If
```

as i said, in the next refresh, 02XC 'll be change to a four other random number.
I want to get the ID or classname for each refresh to manipulate the table.
or every others ways that could help me to manage the table.
sorry my English is so poor. hope your understand me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute = value selector with starts with (`^`) operator

```
[id^='1554799061475-1-uiGrid-']
```

I am not sure if you want a single or multiple matches

single match

```
Dim ele As Object
Set ele = objHtml.querySelector("[id^='1554799061475-1-uiGrid-']")
```

This assumes the id starts with `1554799061475-1-uiGrid-` and only the end bit changes.

You can use `querySelectorAll` to return a nodeList if more than one match possible.

Comment: Hello @QHarr Thanks for your answer. its pushed me a bid ahead. the problems is, i'm 28 tables to fill and each of them has the same prefix ID. if i use queryselector, VBA does not which table i'm calling and my program froze.  Is there a code that will help me to get the ID of a table in each refresh so that i can use it next???

Comment: You should be able to access by index. Queryselectorall returns a nodelist so item(0) will be the first etc. Does they match up with your tables or are you only interested in certain tables?

Comment: i'm interested by certain table. can you write the code down please.

Comment: I need to seem more html. I don't fully understand what you are asking. If you don't know the id but want to extract the id for certain tables you will need a different way to select the tables and then extract the id. The html you show is for a div element, not a table.

Comment: Hey! @QHarr and thanks for you help. its really not the table but the div. In fact, the "div" correspond to the days of the month, and for each day, I have to record a value. but there are also some days that I can not save a value. particulary the six first table. i start to record my values in the seventh "div". i want to upload picture by i cant here. please check  https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1961441/logiciels/microsoft-office/excel/macros-vba-excel/vba-manipuler-angularj/   to see how lookslike the place i want to record values. i asked this some question to another forum

Comment: I'm not sure how they line up. It might be something like: objHtml.querySelectorAll("[id^='1554799061475-1-uiGrid-']").item(6)   I need the html to work with if you find you can pastebin.com the page html.